Find all matches that use the 4 digits in sheet1 to find the 10 digit phone numbers by matching the last 4 numbers in sheet2
Find all matches that use the 4 digits in sheet1 column A to find the phone numbers by matching the last 4 numbers in sheet2 column b and then put the full phone number(s) in column B in sheet1. The code I use works but it doesn't show all the matches. I want to match all so some of the 4 digits may have multiple matches. The code I have in sheet1 Column B1 is
=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B, MATCH(RIGHT(A3,4), RIGHT(Sheet2!A:A,4), 0))

Sheet1



A
B
C




7413
4802227413



7414
4802227414



7419
#N/A



7420
#N/A



7425
#N/A



7426
#N/A



7427
#N/A



7405
4802227405



7406
4802227406




Sheet2



A
B
C




7413
4802227413



7414
4802227414



7406
4802227406



7420
4802227420



7405
4802227405



7426
4802227426



7427
4802227427



7405
6025557405



7406
6025557406




Example Output



A
B
C




7413
4802227413



7414
4802227414



7419
#N/A



7420
#N/A



7425
#N/A



7426
#N/A



7427
#N/A



7405
4802227405
6025557405


7406
4802227406
6025557406




This is what you need to do, to accomplish the desired output :


=IFERROR(INDEX($F$3:$F$11,MATCH(1,(B3<>$F$3:$F$11)*(A3=--RIGHT($F$3:$F$11,4)),0)),"")


Alternative methods if applicable to excel versions:
=IFNA(FILTER($F$3:$F$11,((B3<>$F$3:$F$11)*(A3=--RIGHT($F$3:$F$11,4))),""),"")


=IFNA(XLOOKUP(1,((B3<>$F$3:$F$11)*(A3=--RIGHT($F$3:$F$11,4))),$F$3:$F$11,""),"")


NOTE: Change ranges and cell references as per your suit.

In Reference to the context of the post:
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(1,(B3<>Sheet2!B:B)*(A3=--RIGHT(Sheet2!B:B,4)),0)),"")


Updated with additional formulas:
As per comments from OP:

Thank you that worked!! One more question, what would I need to change
if I wanted to find a 3rd for 4th number that matches 7405 and have it
show in column D and or column E




=IFERROR(INDEX($F$3:$F$11,
 AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW($F$3:$F$11)-ROW($F$3)+1)/
 ((B3<>$F$3:$F$11)*(A3=--RIGHT($F$3:$F$11,4))),
 COUNTIFS(A$3:A3,A3))),"")



Thank you that worked!! One more question, what would I need to change if I wanted to find a 3rd for 4th number that matches 7405 and have it show in column D and or column E

@DerekLong then this won't work because it becomes a duplicate reference you will need to use INDEX()+AGGREGATE() or can use FILTER() function with INDEX()+COUNTIFS()

@DerekLong see I have an update for you. Hope it helps!
